# Is 0' of PA degree relative to a non-low set?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

**Definitions:**

A set $X$ is *of PA degree relative to a set $Y$* if every infinite $Y$-computable binary tree has an infinite $X$-computable path.
A set $X$ is *low* if $X'$ is computable from $\emptyset'$.

**Easy facts:**

By the relativized Low basis theorem and using the fact that a low relative to a low is still low, $\emptyset'$ is of PA degree relative to every low set.
Of course, if $\emptyset'$ is of PA degree relative to a set $X$, then $X$ is $\emptyset'$-computable.

**Question:**

> Are there non-low set $Y$ such that $0'$ is of PA degree relative to $Y$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, by the Arslanov completeness criterion $0'$ is only DNC (Diagonally non-computable) relative to low sets. And PA implies DNC.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm ashamed not to have found it by myself.